# pub error installing http

Tags: dart, package, installation

Trying to install the http package, the latest of which is version 0.11.3+13, and found [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/http)

When I put it in my pubspec.yaml in my project, I get this:

> Package http has no versions that match >=0.11.3+13 <0.12.0 derived from:
>   - observables depends on version ^0.11.3+13

Here's my pubspec.yaml (note I've temporarily commented out 'angular2' and 'rxdart'.

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.20.1 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  # angular2: ^2.2.0
  # rxdart: ^0.10.2
  http: ^0.11.3+13

dev_dependencies:
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1

transformers:
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES'
    platform_pipes:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
    entry_points: web/main.dart
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

I was able to download the package (that version).  Here is its pubspec.yaml:

```
name: http
version: 0.11.3+13
author: "Dart Team <misc@dartlang.org>"
homepage: https://github.com/dart-lang/http
description: A composable, Future-based API for making HTTP requests.
dependencies:
  async: "^1.10.0"
  collection: "^1.5.0"
  http_parser: ">=0.0.1 <4.0.0"
  path: ">=0.9.0 <2.0.0"
  stack_trace: ">=0.9.1 <2.0.0"
dev_dependencies:
  unittest: ">=0.9.0 <0.12.0"
environment:
  sdk: ">=1.23.0-dev.0.0 <2.0.0"
```

And, here is the output of pub get listing all the packages and versions it could install (by removing the http package):

```
  analyzer 0.29.10 (0.30.0-alpha.2 available)
  angular2 2.2.0 (3.0.0-beta+1 available)
  args 0.13.7
  async 1.13.2
  barback 0.15.2+10
  browser 0.10.0+2
  build 0.5.0 (0.8.0 available)
  charcode 1.1.1
  cli_util 0.0.1+2
  code_transformers 0.5.1
  collection 1.14.0
  convert 2.0.1
  crypto 2.0.1
  csslib 0.13.5
  dart_style 0.2.16 (1.0.3 available)
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter 1.0.2
  fixnum 0.10.5
  glob 1.1.3
  html 0.13.1
  http_parser 3.1.1
  intl 0.14.0 (0.15.0 available)
  isolate 1.0.0
  js 0.6.1
  logging 0.11.3+1
  meta 1.0.5
  mime 0.9.3
  observable 0.14.0+1 (0.20.4+1 available)
  package_config 1.0.0
  path 1.4.1
  plugin 0.2.0
  pool 1.3.0
  protobuf 0.5.4
  rxdart 0.10.2
  shelf 0.6.7+2


  shelf_static 0.2.4
  source_maps 0.10.4
  source_span 1.3.1
  stack_trace 1.7.3
  stream_channel 1.6.1
  string_scanner 1.0.1
  typed_data 1.1.3
  utf 0.9.0+3
  watcher 0.9.7+3
  when 0.2.0
  which 0.1.3
  yaml 2.1.12
```

Two observations:

1. When I try a 'pub upgrade', nothing changes, even though the 'get' output shows there are later versions available.
2. Looking at the dependencies in the http package, they all seem to reference valid versions in the 'get' output.

So, if observables depends on version ^0.11.3+13, and that's the version I'm trying to install, and it's definitely findable on github, why is it complaining?

I've been scouring through the bug reports and the consensus is that it's a version dependency problem, supposedly easily fixable.  But I don't see any conflicts or out-of-version dependencies, here.  And, I don't have a clue as to how to find and fix, if that's the case.

Is there a way to manually install the package, or would that just break things more?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading. It just means that `pub` can't find a matching set of dependencies.

In your case I'm pretty sure it's the SDK constraint in the `http` version you're using

https://github.com/dart-lang/http/blob/0.11.3%2B13/pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=1.23.0-dev.0.0 <2.0.0"
```

Comment: How's that?

The package's environment/sdk spec is exactly the same as in my project:

Theirs:
> sdk: ">=1.23.0-dev.0.0 <2.0.0"

Mine:
> sdk: '>=1.20.1 <2.0.0

Comment: Well, that didn't come out well....  anyway, I'm using dart 1.22.1.  How do I find the SDK version?

Comment: Yours supports `>=1.20.1`, `http` requires `>=1.23.0-dev.0.0`. Not sure what to make of your comments. I think you need either a newer Dart version or allow older `http` versions.

Comment: Ok, if it supports >=1.20.1 (and <2.0.0), 1.23 falls within that range, right?  So, is my SDK version the same as the 'dart --version' return (which is 1.22.1) (I ask this because in many dev environments, the tools and the SDKs aren't necessarily the same version)?

Comment: Looking on the downloads site, it looks like 1.23 is a dev version, and 1.22 is the stable version.  I'm using brew to install on Mac, which pulls the stable version.  I guess I need to yank that and try the dev version...

Comment: Your version `1.22.1` is not within the range required by `http`. Yes `dart --version` prints the version of your Dart SDK. The tools shipped with the SDK can have their own versions, but they are aligned to work with that version of course.

Comment: `1.23.0-dev.0.0` definitely is a `dev` version as the `-dev` in the version says.